# How to make an array in shell?

Tags: linux, shell

Now I use an ugly way to create arrays in shell, e.g.

```
ARG_ARRAY=(num1 num2 num3 num4 num5 num6 num7 num8 num9 num10)
```

Can this be more elegant ? like the C way, e.g.

```
ARG_ARRAY=num[10]
```

Comment: You cannot create arrays in Bourne shell, because Bourne shell does not support arrays.  You can create arrays in bash, zsh, ksh, and other shells, but you cannot "make an array in shell".  Shells vary, and the word "shell" by itself implies Bourne shell (not bash).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ ARG_ARRAY=(num{1..10})

$ echo ${ARG_ARRAY[@]}
num1 num2 num3 num4 num5 num6 num7 num8 num9 num10
```

Comment: Should `ARG_ARRAY=(num{1..10})` be `ARG_ARRAY=$(num{1..10})`?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to explicitly declare that `ARG_ARRAY` is an array, use (bash):

```
declare -a ARG_ARRAY
```

Then you can set its values with:

```
ARG_ARRAY[$index]=whatever
```

You cannot specify a size for an indexed array, indexed you haven't set will simply be empty if you try to access them.

Comment: Actually, `declare` is not needed unless you're making an associative array. Arrays in Bash with normal integers used as keys are created dynamically on assignment, so `ARG_ARRAY[$index]=whatever` is just as good. Of course, doing a `declare` improves readability and never hurts. :)

Comment: Correct, not required but gives a hint. Since OP seems to be trying to declare an array, I thought that would help.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to declare an array *constant* you can do that easily after setting the value:

```
$ ARG_ARRAY=(num1 num2 num3 num4 num5 num6 num7 num8 num9 num10)
$ declare -r ARG_ARRAY
```

This obviously protects the whole array:

```
$ ARG_ARRAY=(new)
bash: ARG_ARRAY: readonly variable
```

It also protects individual elements from being changed:

```
$ ARG_ARRAY[0]=new
bash: ARG_ARRAY: readonly variable
```

...and inserted:

```
$ ARG_ARRAY[20]=new
bash: ARG_ARRAY: readonly variable
```